# Partially Non Standard Text Extraction from PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this pdf table data which looks standard but when I extract the whole text into a string object the data is extracted in "bunches" from same column rather than line by line. Screenshots attached.

Sample pdf file [attached here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G4U2N2QoiUg2QA-lWGFF00-aj6roo8HK/view?usp=sharing)

I just need data from 2 columns - 1) Security Name 2) Market Value in Deal
CCY/Market Value in Fund CCY

```
import sys
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    print('You passed in: ' + path)
    text = extract_text(path)
    return text

#Filepath = sys.argv[1]

Filepath = 'Portfolio.pdf'

PDFtext = convert_pdf_to_txt(Filepath)
print(PDFtext)
```

After extracting the pdf data in 'PDFtext' string, I am unable to figure out how to parse these 2 required columns in Excel due to inconsistency in string structure.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi trim or split them by new line character

Comment: Thanks but simple trim at new line will not work as the extracted data extracts 1-3 rows data from same column together. See screenshot

Comment: So I think there is one solution only. If there is one excel sheet, you have to do it by hand or if there are multiple sheets but in the same format, you can handle them by if conditions. There is no way.

Comment: I am not sure why my question was downvoted!
Can anyone suggest what did I miss?

Comment: I think that because you did not make more search about it, it was down voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I did some more research I found out that the library `pdfminer.high_level` does not help me extract data line by line(in this particular case of the pdf) but `pdfplumber` did and so I modified my codes to below -

`pdfminer.high_level` has been very helpful in the past with different data extraction requirements where data was pretty much standard way organized.

```
import pdfplumber
import sys
Filepath = sys.argv[1]

pdf = pdfplumber.open(Filepath)
page = pdf.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
print(text)
pdf.close()
```